# ElasticSearch bool search using array

Tags: arrays, filter, elasticsearch, boolean-search

I would like to be able to exclude a number of nodes in my ElasticSearch query. Currently this code is working perfectly, but it will only exclude two nodes ($nodeId1 and $nodeId2).

How would I change this query so I can use an array which would contain as many node IDs as I want? Thank you.

```
$data_string = '{
    "from" : 0, "size" : "' . $maximumResults . '",
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match" : {
                    "thread.title" : {
                        "query" : "' . $threadTitle . '",
                        "operator": "or"
                    }
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "bool" : {
                    "must" : [],
                    "must_not" : [
                        {
                            "term" : {"thread.discussion_id" : "' . $currentThreadId . '"}
                        }, 
                        { 
                            "term" : {"thread.node" : "' . $nodeId1 . '"}
                        },
                        { 
                            "term" : {"thread.node" : "' . $nodeId2 . '"}
                        }                                       
                    ],
                    "should" : []
                }
            }
        }
    }
}';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the terms filter:

```
$data_string = '{
    "from" : 0, "size" : "' . $maximumResults . '",
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match" : {
                    "thread.title" : {
                        "query" : "' . $threadTitle . '",
                        "operator": "or"
                    }
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "bool" : {
                    "must" : [],
                    "must_not" : [
                        {
                            "term" : {"thread.discussion_id" : "' . $currentThreadId . '"}
                        }, 
                        { 
                            "terms" : {"thread.node" : ["' . $nodeId1 . '", "' . $nodeId2 . '", "' . $nodeId3 . '"}
                        }                                       
                    ],
                    "should" : []
                }
            }
        }
    }
}';
```

Comment: Thank you, Dan. That is exactly the information I needed and your example worked great. I ended up creating a simple $whereclause and now I can easily add as many nodeIds as I want.